# Do BTRFS self-healing mechanisms apply when a folder of the host with BTRFS enabled storage is remotely mounted by a different host?

Tags: webdav, btrfs, data-consistency

the file system BTRFS comes with some useful features regarding data consistency/error detection and correction (let's call them self healing mechanisms). Given the following situation, will these mechanisms apply?

Server with BTRFS storage <--> WebDAV <--> Client PC

The client PC uses a WebDAV mount (or another remote mount type with the help of any other protocol) to access files on the server.

Now: When opening a file on the client side and closing it without changes AND given a bitflip during that time what is supposed to happen? What I assume so far is the following:

Bitflips happening on the server side while dealing with the files in the mount would be no problem because BTRFS will cover that. Bitflips on the client side will not be handled by the servers BTRFS mechanisms because the servers underlying BTRFS does not know if a flipped bit is actually a wanted change to the file. The remote mount makes it a blackbox for BTRFS, doesn't it?

Is this on a high level correct so far?

Comment: since the storage is btrfs, and does not change the filesystem, imho all will be affected by btrfs features. I. e. Smb just tranlaste the data in a other "language" so that standard system ls can talk to each other even if they are totally different. but this question can mostly only answered by opinions imho

Answer (score 1):

the protection that btrfs offers is between the write to disk and the read to disk that occurs locally on the server in the kernel filesystem code.  Once the file is in memory on the server, on the network or in the client, other mechanisms are needed to prevent (very rare) bitflip corruption.